# Solr stop words aren't getting results

Tags: solr

Having an issue with solr stop words. It correctly removes all the stop words I want however the blank "position" tokens it leaves seems to be messing up my search results.

For example, I want a query for "I want to go hiking" to return "hiking" but it doesn't even though "I", "want", "to" and "go" are all stopwords. When I used the admin page analyzer it shows that after running through the stopwords filter "hiking" still has a position of 5 which I assume is why I don't get any results during a query. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the StopFilterFactory in both the index and query analyzers when defining the fieldType?

Comment: No I'm not, only when querying because the only things I'm indexing are one or two word descriptions